# Why is the elif statement taking priority over my if statement?

Tags: if-statement

So I've got a number guessing game, all my previous code works fine, and you can probably see that I have the randomly generated number printed on the screen. But when I guess the number correctly I still get told I am wrong?

```
num = randrange(0, 100)

if num > 0 and num < 50:

print("The number is greater than 0 but smaller than 50")

elif num > 50 and num < 100:

print("The number is smaller than 100 but greater than 50")

print(num)

print('Start Guessing')

a = input()


a = input()
if a == num:

print ("You got the correct number, woohoo")

elif num > 0 and num < 20:

print ("Hint: The number is bigger than 0 but smaller than 20")

elif num > 20 and num < 40:

print ('Hint: The number is bigger than 20 but smaller than 40')

elif num > 40 and num < 60:

print ('Hint: The number is bigger than 40 but smaller than 60')

elif num > 60 and num < 80:

print ('Hint: The number is bigger than 60 but smaller than 80')

elif num > 80 and num < 100:

print ('Hint: The number is bigger than 80 but smaller than 100')
```

Sorry for the weird looking code, I've never used this site before.

Comment: Hi! What programming language is this?

Comment: Also, what specifically are you seeing output?  The text from the last `elif` block? From the first one?

Comment: `"all my previous code works fine"` What previous code? The variable `num` appears to be a numeric value. What type of variable does `input()` return? Why do you call `input()` twice? What if `num` is equal to 50? It won't be displayed. What if `num` is equal to 20, 40, 60 or 80? None of your if clauses will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be Python. You should indicate that in a tag. Also, since Python if statements rely on indentation you should post your code with proper indentation.

In the code:

```
a = input()
if a == num:
```

You are comparing a string to a number. You should cast `a` to an `int`.

```
if int(a) == num:
```